# Routing code working in ASP.NET MVC 5.0 no longer works in 5.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have code that runs on application start that prefixes all of my routes with a `{lang}` parameter.

The intent is to transform any URL like `/page` to `{lang}/page`, with `{lang}` being a language code ("en", "fr"...).

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    foreach (var r in routes.OfType<Route>())
        r.Url = "{lang}/" + r.Url;
}
```

This works fine on ASP.NET MVC 5.0. For example this action shows the About page on both `/en/about-us` and `/fr/about-us`:

```
[Route("about-us", Name = "About")]
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

(the `{lang}` parameter is read in `OnActionExecuting` and sets the UI culture accordingly.)

However, it no longer works on ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3.

On this version, the page remains accessible on `/abous-us`, and `/en/about-us` and `/fr/about-us` return a 404.
It is like the modified routes are not taken into account.

I tried to dig into `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` to troubleshoot but it looks like the code, and in particular the `AttributeRoutingMapper` class, was completely rewritten between the 2 versions.

Is there anything I can do to have my modified routes taken into account?

Comment: Did you actually invoke `RegisterRoutes`? You haven't provided a [MCVE].

Comment: Sure, here's a full repro: https://github.com/xps/repro1017
I would expect to be able to navigate to /en/about-us and see "Lang : en" on the page.

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE] in your question itself.

Comment: Come on, there is no way I can paste a whole web project (startup code, routing config, controllers, views...) in the question itself. I have included the bits that are relevant. The rest of the code is standard. I have literally changed less than 10 lines from the default template. And yes, the RegisterRoutes method is called from the Application_Start event (as it is by default when you create a new web app). In the repro I posted I have also made sure to make the few modifications to the default web app template in a separate commit.

Comment: Of course you can provide a [mcve]. Just narrow it down to the minimal amount of code necessary that still reproduces the issue. GitHub is not acceptable, you must provide enough code directly in your question to repro the issue so that the question remains useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifying already registered routes, preferred approach would be to use **RoutePrefix** attribute on controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("{lang}")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("~/", Name = "Index")] // Use ~ to skip prefix or use optional {lang?} as prefix
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("about-us", Name = "About")]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    [Route("contact", Name = "Contact")]
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
    ...
}
```

as to why it is not working, unfortunately without looking at the code or comparing routes in both versions you will not have any logical answer.

Comment: It's not exactly the same as this requires updating each controller but still, that solves my  problem, so thank you.